# I want to get user access token rather than application access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

I want to get user access token because I need to get user's posts and comments.

When I use Graph API Explorer, the access token it generates is correct one and shows me my posts and comments and some other data. But when try to get posts and comments by using this code than it does not return me posts and comments and return some other data only which i don't need.

```
 require_once('facebook.php');

 $config = array(
    'appId' => '383128895071077',
    'secret' => '6a9ab479186f53db5c531a3fa5f91be0',
 );

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/', array('access_token' => $access_token));
```

I searched all the google and get access token by different ways but I could not get posts and comments of me. I must be doing something wrong and need to sort out this as soon as possible. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this example
[Facebook php sdk example](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php)

you should check whether we have user access token like this

```
   // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    // We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
    //
    // If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
    // Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
    // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

    if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}
```

Once we get the user details, you can ensure that user is logged into app and authorized the app.

**For feeds**
You should have [extended permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#extended_perms) read_stream

then you can read the wall feed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was read_stream which I was missing, I was using only publish_stream in scope whereas I needed read_stream to read posts and comments.